# Python 2: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20.0'

Tags: python, math

I have a small problem with a math in python. So I have a few variables, `x`, `y` and `answer`:

```
>>>x = 20
>>>y = 21
>>>answer = x / y * 100
>>>answer
0
```

So it's prints out null. OK i know that it's prints out null because i had to print `x = 20.0` instead of print `x = 20`.

But anyway I need it to print out:

```
95.2380952381
```

How can I do that?

Note: I can't just write `x = 20.0`?

And also I have tried to do this like this:

```
x1 = str(x) + '.0'
result = int(x1) / y * 100
```

But Python give me an error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20.0'
```

So how can I fix this?

Comment: null is not the same thing as 0.

Comment: Note that Python 3.x will output `95.23809523809523`, whereas Python 2.x will output `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `from __future__ import division` to make *all* division float division.

Alternatively, use `float()` instead of `int()` to interpret a string as a floating point number instead:

```
answer = float(x) / y * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
>>> answer = float(x) / y * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

use `float(x)/y*100` instead of `int()`

but this would just fixed the error, but what you tried to achieve can be done in this way
`answer = x/y*100.`

Answer (score 0):

Python thinks you are doing integer division (since `x`, `y` are integers).  To fix this, you can use `float()` to convert one of `x` or `y` to float.:

```
answer = float(x) / y * 100
```